# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el costo total si la subconsulta devuelve más de un valor MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito sacar el total de una renta realizada y dicha renta cuenta con dos películas. Cada película tiene un costo diferente. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para sacar el costo total de la renta? Al hacerlo de esta forma no me permite por los dos valores que devuelve la subconsulta. ¿Cómo puedo formularlo?

```
SELECT SUM(costo) 
FROM peliculas
WHERE idPeli= (
    SELECT idPeli
    FROM renta 
    WHERE idRenta='7' GROUP BY idPeli
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es probable que ésto solucione tu inconveniente:

```
SELECT SUM(costo) 
FROM peliculas
WHERE idPeli in (
               SELECT idPeli
               FROM renta 
               WHERE idRenta='7'
              )
```

Tu subconsulta devuelve un conjunto de idPeli, y tu consulta externa, va a sumar el costo de las pelis que posean un id que esta dentro del conjunto devuelto por tu subconsulta.

Espero que te sirva